# Run Background nodejs Process on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

I have a nodejs/swagger project that I'm running on a virtual Ubuntu instance for a class I'm taking right now, and I'd like to be able to just have it run in the background. I'm clearly able to connect to the project, except the API seems to go awry when I close my PuTTY sessions, regardless of how I run the project.

I've used every combination of `nohup`, `detach`, `&`, and `screen` to run this, and somehow, each time, I get the exact same behavior: when I open a PuTTY session (or, for that matter, when I log in via the VBox screen through the host - I don't have to do *anything*, I just have to log in somehow it seems), the API seems to go back up, and when I close PuTTY (or logout in the VBox screen), the API seemingly crashes.

I say seemingly because I'm not familiar with nodejs or swagger, but what I can say is that when I'm logged in, `http://localhost:3000/viewer/` gives me the interactive page that it's supposed to, whereas when I'm logged out, `http://localhost:3000/viewer/` returns the same thing as `http://localhost:3000/api/` when I'm logged in: `{"message":"Cannot read property 'apiPath' of undefined"}` (which, if I'm not mistaken, is a JSON object?).

All I can say is that it seems to have something to do with the way I installed nodejs (I used `nvm install 4.1.0` instead of `apt-get install nodejs-legacy`), because I noticed that when I logout and then log back in, if I don't include `nvm use v4.1.0` at the end of my `.bashrc`, then Ubuntu doesn't recognize `node` or `npm` or `swagger` as commands. For reference, this is the rest of what I've added to my `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/pockets/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use v4.1.0
```

Comment: Running `nvm alias default v4.1.0` does not resolve the problem.